# Внутри длинных циклов for не выполняются транзакции indexedDB

Tags: javascript, циклы, асинхронность, indexeddb

Пробую для себя решить задачу расстановки 12 коней на шахматной доске так, чтобы они били все клетки шахматной доски. При тестировании кода выяснилось, что перебор вариантов на моей машине занимает более 6 часов (более 100 млрд перестановок). Решил сделать промежуточное сохранение данных, чтобы расчёты можно было прерывать и продолжать с точки останова. Пробую сохранять данные с помощью indexedDB.
Выяснилось, что до конца работы цикла транзакция по сохранению данных в indexedDB не завершается.

Чтобы смоделировать проблему для stackoverflow, я написал модельный скрипт, который создаёт базу данных indexedDB, считывает оттуда промежуточные результаты, вызывает функцию testFunction(), внутри которой цикл по таймеру работает 20 секунд и каждые 5 секунд пытается создать транзакцию, сохраняющую время вызова транзакции.

Рабочая копия скрипта находится в [codepen](https://codepen.io/sowlushka/pen/ZEVxpZM).
Если дождаться окончания выполнения скрипта, то в indexedDB добавятся в качестве массива String новые значения таймера когда была поставлена транзакция в очередь. В этом можно убедиться, если запустить скрипт повторно. Однако если не давать циклу отработать до конца перезагрузкой страницы со скриптом, то ни одна транзакция в indexedDB так и не сохранится. Перезапуск скрипта покажет только последние 4 значения удачно отработавшего цикла. Как мне переделать код, чтобы все транзакции выполнялись (сохраняли данные) до окончания цикла?

```js
"use strict";

//Разрешить выполнять для codepen длительные циклы
if(window.CP?.PenTimer.MAX_TIME_IN_LOOP_WO_EXIT){
  window.CP.PenTimer.MAX_TIME_IN_LOOP_WO_EXIT=30000;//Разрешить выполнение 30 секунд
}

const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("ru", {
  minute: "numeric",
  second: "numeric"
});//Формат вывода даты часы: минуты: секунды

const dbName="worker";
let db;//Объект базы данных
let currentTimer=0;//Промежуточный таймер, который будем сохранять в indexedDB
let timerArray=[];//Массив значений таймера

let openRequest = indexedDB.open(dbName, 1);
openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function() {
  // Создаём базу данных
  db = openRequest.result;
  const store = db.createObjectStore("workerObjects",{keyPath: 'variable', autoIncrement: false});

  //Начальная инициализация значений в базе данных при её создании
  //Сохраняем начальные значения переменных в базу данных
  store.put({variable: "currentTimer", value: currentTimer});
  store.put({variable: "timerArray", value: timerArray});
};

openRequest.onsuccess = function() {
  db = openRequest.result;
  let transaction = db.transaction("workerObjects", "readwrite");
  let worker=transaction.objectStore("workerObjects");
  const request=worker.getAll();
  request.onsuccess=(e)=>{
    const dbData = request.result;
    currentTimer=dbData.find(el=>el.variable=="currentTimer");
    currentTimer=currentTimer?currentTimer.value:0;
    timerArray=dbData.find(el=>el.variable=="timerArray").value;
  }
  transaction.oncomplete=()=>{
    showMessage("Получено из indexedDB при старте: ");
    setTimeout(testFunction,1);
  }

}

function testFunction(){
  const startTime=performance.now();
  const finishTime=startTime+20*1000;//Цикл будет выполняться 20 секунд 
  for(let i=startTime;i<finishTime; i=performance.now()){
    if(!(i%5000) && currentTimer!=i){
      //Каждые 5 секунд сохраняем в indexedDB последнее значение таймера и обновляем массив таймеров

      timerArray.push(formatter.format(new Date()));
      let transaction = db.transaction("workerObjects", "readwrite");
      let worker=transaction.objectStore("workerObjects");
      worker.put({variable: "currentTimer", value: i});
      worker.put({variable: "timerArray", value: timerArray});
      currentTimer=i;//За 1 мс for делает без этого условия несколько заходов в блок if
    }
  }
  showMessage("Данные, полученные после завершения цикла:");//Выводим результаты вычислений после отработки функции
}

function showMessage(msg){
  let result=document.getElementById("indexedDB-result");
  if (!result){
    document.querySelector("body").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",'<div id="indexedDB-result"></div>');
  }
  let out=`<div class="one-message">
             <div>${msg}</div>
             <div>Таймер: ${currentTimer}</div>
             <div>Массив: [${timerArray.join(", ")}]</div>
           </div>`;
    document.getElementById("indexedDB-result").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",out);
  
}

clear.onclick=(e)=>{
  indexedDB.deleteDatabase(dbName);
}
```

```css
.one-message{
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="clear">Очистить БД</button>
</body>
```

Comment: `await new Promise(setTimeout)`

Comment: Но вообще-то надо алгоритм улучшать.

Comment: Пробовал промисы. Но вроде как не получилось. Возможно что-то криво сделал. Через ServiceWorker получается передать сообщение и обработать в другом процессе, но пока хочется попытаться без него.